# Executing Linux executable file in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows

I have a php application on localhost (hosted on Wamp on Windows) and in the future I would like to host it on a Windows server. From the php, I would like to execute Linux executable program. Is there anyway to do that ?

Note :
I cannot compile the linux program on windows since I don't have the source code.

Comment: In short, no. There are two venerable ways to execute Unix programs on Windows: [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) and [MinGW](http://mingw.org/). These both require recompiling the program to run in their quirky unix pseudo-environments.

Comment: Also, for my money's worth, hosting on a Linux server would be much more reliable, and conservative of precious resources.

Comment: In general, you need Linux to run a Linux executable. However you could run Linux in a virtual machine on Windows, and then connect from php to what VM. However, that isn't really on-topic for StackOverflow.